# Why does IntelliJ IDEA update resources even when no changes are made?

Tags: intellij-idea

Every time I alt tab out of IntelliJ IDEA, it keeps updating resources triggering the live reload even when no changes are made. Why is that?

The expected behavior is to update resources only when changes are made.

I'm using Spring boot with kotlin as the programming language. Thymeleaf templates keep updating even without any changes.

The IntelliJ IDEA version I'm using is 2019.1.2

Comment: Could you please provide some more information?

Comment: @andreas what do you want to know?

Comment: In which language do you program?

Comment: @andreas Just edited the question.

Comment: Please check that "Update resources" action isn't selected for "On frame deactivation" in your run configuration.